# replace part of request_uri before passing it to proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

i'm trying to replace specific part or request_uri using rewrite, but it won't work for some reason

example url: http://example.com:3000/?soft=55191&src1=changethis&src2=HOME&type=0&id=7700458

```
server {

       server_name example.com;
       listen 3000;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        rewrite ^(?<=&src1=)(.*)(?=&src2)$ changewiththis$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://example2.com;
    }

}
```

so the Goal here is to replace the exact string between 'src1=' and '&src2' so it can be passed to proxy_pass with the changed string

Comment: In what way isn't it working? What is the behaviour you're seeing and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: @CalumHalpin the regex aren't matching anything, my goal here is to replace part of the requested url using 'rewrite' when this happen proxy_pass should use that modified url
so at the rewrite line in my example code it should take $request_uri and match any string between '&src1=' and '&src2' in it, then replace that match with another string

Answer (score 2):

The `location` and `rewrite` directives use a [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which does not include the query string (anything from the `?` onwards).

To manipulate the query string, you will need to look at the `$request_uri` or `$args` variables, or the individual parameters using the `$arg_` family of variables (e.g. `$arg_src1`).

The simplest solution may be to use a `map` directive to manipulate `$request_uri` before passing the new value upstream.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $changethis {
default                                           $request_uri;
~(?<prefix>.*[?](|.*&)src1)=[^&]*(?<suffix>.*)$   $prefix=newvalue$suffix;
}

server {
    ...
    location / {
        resolver ...;
        proxy_pass http://example.com$changethis;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

Comment: Richard can helpme with ~(?<prefix>.*[?](|.*&)src1)=[^&]*(?<suffix>.*)$   in case what I want remplace in request uri is this.  Example:   
http://example.com/somepath/somepath_replaceonlythis/index.html
What I want replace is only what is between  _ and /

Comment: ~(?<prefix>.*_)[^\/]*(?<suffix>.*)$  ok here solved with proper reg expersion,  but now how  set my custom value on $prefix=newvalue$suffix;     I cant use _ instead =