# Nginx $args manipulation for proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to work out how to modify $args before using them in a set variable command.
I am moving from a service that uses the addresses formatted like this
http://server/proxy/account?mp=/stream

and need them to be sent to the new service  like this
http://server:2000/system/proxy.php?unique_id=account&mounturl=stream

so far i have been able to use
this location block to get the stream account name

```
    `location ~ ^/proxy//?([^/]+)/?([^/]+)? {
        set $proxy_url https://127.0.0.1:2000/system/proxy.php?unique_id=$1&mounturl=$2;

        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        proxy_set_header                User-Agent "$http_user_agent [ip:$remote_addr]";
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5;
        proxy_send_timeout 15;
        proxy_read_timeout 15;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass $proxy_url;
        expires off;
        client_max_body_size 1M;
        tcp_nodelay on;
}
```

however i cannot work out what i need to use to change the mount point from /stream to just stream

im aware i can just use $arg_mp as a variable to use it directly but i need to present it without the leading slash, and frankly i dont have any hair left to pull out, can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: The solution is probably the same as [my unaccepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281041/replace-part-of-request-uri-before-passing-it-to-proxy-pass/57286420#57286420).

Comment: Thanks i will give it a try